# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 JAVA mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have encountered an error, java.sql.SQLException:

```
    Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
```

It's super frustrating, because I have been making amendments to the code like changing in the arg to all string, but the error still appears.

```
public void readDataBase(int val, String d1, String d2, String d3, String d4 ) throws     Exception {
try {
// This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// Setup the connection with the DB
connect = DriverManager
.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/MAXdb?"+ "user=root&password=");

// Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
statement = connect.createStatement();
// Result set get the result of the SQL query       
   resultSet = statement
.executeQuery("select * from MAXdb.emcsg");
writeResultSet(resultSet);

// PreparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert into  MAXdb.emcsg values (default,?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
// Parameters start with 1

preparedStatement.setInt(1, val);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, d1);
preparedStatement.setString(3, d2);
preparedStatement.setString(4, d3);
preparedStatement.setString(5, d4);


preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("SELECT  id, Date, Time, Demand, SUPPLY from MAXdb.emcsg");
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
writeResultSet(resultSet);



    } catch (Exception e) {
throw e;
} finally {
close();
}

}
```

My second class:

```
public void Csvreader() throws IOException {
try {
// TODO code application logic here

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:/TEST.csv"));

String  nextLine[];
int i = 1;
Mysql sen = new Mysql();
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
try {
sen.readDataBase( i, nextLine[0], nextLine[1], nextLine[2], nextLine[3] );
i = i+1;
} catch (Exception ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Opencsv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}


} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Opencsv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

}
```

Database:
    Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    id  int(11)         No  None
    Date    text    utf8_general_ci     No  None
    Time    text    utf8_general_ci     No  None
    Demand  text    utf8_general_ci     No  None
    SUPPLY  text    utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I suspect this is the problem:

```
insert into  MAXdb.emcsg values (default,?, ?, ? , ?, ?)
```

You haven't specified which column each of those parameters is meant to refer to - and I suspect you've not got 6 columns. Even if you *do* have 6 columns in the table, it would be a good idea to explicitly state in the SQL which column you mean to use for each parameter.

Comment: I just checked and there's only 5 fields in mysql

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the following statement:

```
insert into  MAXdb.emcsg values (default,?, ?, ? , ?, ?)
```

causes an error. Check if emcsg has 6 columns.

Comment: I just checked and there's only 5 fields in mysql

Answer (score 3):

Had you tried changing this

```
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert into  MAXdb.emcsg values (default,?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
```

to this

```
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert into  MAXdb.emcsg values (?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
```

That might work for you.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solved it just now, but I appreciate it!

Comment: @EugeneWong : Your Welcome. Glad you solved it.  Regards

Answer (score 2):

Do you definitely have six columns in the database table?

Always google an error message or error code. Quite often the first link returned will clearly explain the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks!! I found my mistake a while ago!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that there is a problem with your database structure. I think you don't have all the fields you assume you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature

```
public void readDataBase(int val, String d1, String d2, String d3, String d4 )
```

has 5 variables, but your method call has 6:

```
preparedStatement = connect
.prepareStatement("insert into  MAXdb.emcsg values (default,?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
```

Comment: That doesn't matter, the method could hard code some of the values or calculate them from one or more of the other arguments.

Comment: My previous comment was downvoted. Perhaps I wasn't clear: it doesn't matter how many arguments the method sig has, the important part is that the INSERT statement has the same number of values as the table has columns.

Comment: @PaulMedcraft : My bad, I did noticed, wanted to vote someone else, but seems like clicked at the wrong place. So sorry, my bad. I realized my mistake once i clicked it. Regards

Comment: My bad actually mate, it wasn't downvoted at all!