# returning just created id of insert query

Tags: java, jdbc, insert

Is there a way to receive just acquired id by my insert query?

I am using java.sql package and I heard that there is a way without querying these keys again.

Or isn't?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query to get your result. This query should be run in the same session which was used to perform insert.

```
select last_insert_id();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you try to an auto-increment key value ,then you can see the post :

[Retrive the auto-increment field using PreparedStatement.][1]

[Insert using PreparedStatement. How do I auto-increment the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438288/insert-using-preparedstatement-how-do-i-auto-increment-the-id)
[1]: